# Return value of a select statement

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, select, oledb

I want to retrieve the resulting value of a select statement into a string variable. Like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd1.Connection = GetConnection();
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid = " + text;
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to place the selected treatment value into a string variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Start by avoiding the "...NonQuery" method.  Non-Query means "don't return any value from executing this command."

Comment: Use ExecuteReader() to get a datareader and call Read(0) on the datareader

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`ExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) and not [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx). `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns only the number of rows affected.

```
try
{
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
}
catch (SqlException oError)
{

}
while(dr.Read())
{
    string treatment = dr[0].ToString();
}
```

Or better, use a [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for it.

```
using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(dr.Read())
    {
        string treatment = dr[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

But if your `SqlCommand` returns only `1` column, you can use the [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method. It returns first column of the first row as follows:-

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid = " + text;
string str = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Also you can open your code to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always use parameterized queries. Jeff has a cool blog article called [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Please read it carefully. Also read [DotNetPerl SqlParameter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) article. SQL Injection very important when you are working queries.

Comment: Soner you should recommend to the OP to wrap his ExecutReader() Method be wrapped around a try{}catch

Comment: @DJKRAZE Good idea. Updated.

Comment: I'll stress that this is not a good solution in the big picture.  It answers the question, but does not fix the sql injection issues.

Answer (score 4):

[Execute Scalar: Getting Single Value from the Database](http://www.visualbuilder.com/aspnet/database/tutorial/execute-scalar%3a-getting-single-value-from-the-database/) method to retrieve a single value (for example, an aggregate value) from a database.

```
cmd1.Connection = GetConnection();
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid = " + text;
if(cmd.ExecuteScalar()==null)
{
    var treatment = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Other Way: **[ExecuteReader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx)**

```
try
{
    cmd1.CommandText ="SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid=@patientID";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int PatientID = int.Parse(dr["treatment"]);
    }
    reader.Close();
    ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();//always good idea to do proper cleanup
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Response.Write(exc.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Vishak, you are issuing a cmd1.ExecuteReader() what do you do if there is more than 1 row that's returned..? shouldn't you check if reader.HasRows or do the reader.Read() in a While Loop..??? you are assuming that the query will only return 1 row in that case you need to use the ExecuteScalar()

Comment: Also look at this Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
you have int PatientID= reader.GetOrdinal("treatment"); where is the while loop to read the next records if any..?

Comment: how are you passing back int PatientID = int.Parse(dr["treatment"]);
it's not accessible outside that Try is PatiendID a variable that should be declared in a different scope..?

Comment: +1 for clean code.. but I would ask OP how he plans to return the PatientID you may want to declare that as a Session["PatientID"] or as a Protected Property if we are talking about Web Application or a Property .. I hate to assume but I am going to guess this is a Windows Application

Answer (score 1):

the answer:

```
String res = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

the remark: use parametrized query to prevent sql injection

Comment: this is good but you are assuming that the OP's query will always return 1 record.. also this is not a good example of how to answer the OP's question why not paste in his code with the working solution

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with your example code.

1. You have inline sql, which opens you up to sql injection in a major way.
2. You are using ExecuteNonQuery() which means you get no data back.

   ```
    string sSQL = "SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid = @patientId";
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, GetConnection()); // This may be slight different based on what `GetConnectionReturns`, just put the connection string in the second parameter.


       cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientId", text);
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
       string returnValue;
       while(reader.Read())
       {
          returnValue = reader[0].ToString();
       }
   ```

Comment: Where is the Select Statement in your example.. ?

Comment: Hrm, lost it in translation somewhere.  I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the ExecuteScalar method of the command - this will give you the value at the first row and column of the result set.

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd1.Connection = GetConnection();
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid = " + text;
var result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

If your SQL statement returns more than one row/column then you can use ExecuteReader().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OleDbAdapter.

```
string connection = "your connection";
string query = "SELECT treatment FROM appointment WHERE patientid = " + text;
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

Comment: Cristoleg, he can do this without using OleDBAdapter

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection dbConnect = new SqlConnection("your SQL connection string");    
string name = " 'ProjectName' ";
string strPrj = "Select e.type, (e.surname +' '+ e.name) as fulln from dbo.tblEmployees e where id_prj = " + name;
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strPrj, dbConnect);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strPrj, dbConnect);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dbConnect.Open();
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnect.Close();
```